# A series of DeviceSetupManager warnings in Windows 10 event logs

Tags: windows-10, event-log

I have been "cleaning up" Windows 10, and I'm noticing a series of warnings in the Event Viewer every time I start Windows. And they are in the following order.

```
Event 202, DeviceSetupManager
"The Network List Manager reports no connectivity to the internet."

Event 200, DeviceSetupManager
"A connection to the Windows Update service could not be established."

Event 202, DeviceSetupManager
"The Network List Manager reports no connectivity to the internet."

Event 201, DeviceSetupManager
"A connection to the Windows Metadata and Internet Services (WMIS) could not be established."

Event 202, DeviceSetupManager
"The Network List Manager reports no connectivity to the internet."

Event 200, DeviceSetupManager
"A connection to the Windows Update service could not be established."

Event 131, DeviceSetupManager
"Metadata staging failed, result={00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF} for container '0x80070490'"
```

It seems that Event 202 repeats every other instance until I finally get the error: Event 131. What would I have to do to fix these problems, so they stop showing up every time in Event Viewer?

Comment: Is this useful? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/multiple-errors-in-event-viewer-eventid-131-from/e5054c3b-bc91-4beb-894f-4d0d9f0dd8ca?auth=1

Comment: The chosen answer states that the default URL began working again, without the need to change any registry values. I guess I should just wait then.

Comment: Well, how long has the problem been going on?

Comment: Since the Windows 10 release. Maybe I'm being a bit too impatient with MS.

Answer (score 0):

Connect using LAN/Ethernet, set wired autoconfig service to automatic and start the service.